# Android : reading googledrive privatekey.p12 error

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I am trying to get the xxxxxxxxxxxprivatekey.p12 path from the main folder of project. But it is showing the following error.I am very fed up by searching solution for this.Where to store the google drive private key file and how to get the path.Here is the snapshot of my project file hierarchy and error details.Any help is appriciated.Thanks.
This is the example code took from [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/service-accounts)!

```
    private Drive getDriveService(GoogleAccountCredential credential) {
return new Drive.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(), credential)
    .build();
      }
public static Drive getDriveService() throws GeneralSecurityException,
IOException, URISyntaxException {
HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
.setTransport(httpTransport)
.setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
.setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
.setServiceAccountScopes(DriveScopes.DRIVE)
.setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
    new java.io.File(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH))
.build();
Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null)
.setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).build();
return service;
}
```

errorlog :

```
     05-19 20:36:58.914: W/System.err(5175): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-privatekey.p12: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
   05-19 20:36:58.923: W/System.err(5175):  at           libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
   05-19 20:36:58.923: W/System.err(5175):  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
   05-19 20:36:58.923: W/System.err(5175):  at com.google.api.client.auth.security.PrivateKeys.loadFromP12File(PrivateKeys.java:178)
   05-19 20:36:58.933: W/System.err(5175):  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential$Builder.setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(GoogleCredential.java:541)
   05-19 20:36:58.933: W/System.err(5175):  at com.example.drivequickstart.MainActivity.getDriveService(MainActivity.java:172)
   05-19 20:36:58.933: W/System.err(5175):  at com.example.drivequickstart.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:57)
   05-19 20:36:58.933: W/System.err(5175):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
   05-19 20:36:58.933: W/System.err(5175):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
   05-19 20:36:58.933: W/System.err(5175):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
   05-19 20:36:58.933: W/System.err(5175):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
   05-19 20:36:58.933: W/System.err(5175):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
   05-19 20:36:58.933: W/System.err(5175):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
   05-19 20:36:58.943: W/System.err(5175):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  05-19 20:36:58.943: W/System.err(5175):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  05-19 20:36:58.943: W/System.err(5175):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
 05-19 20:36:58.943: W/System.err(5175):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 05-19 20:36:58.943: W/System.err(5175):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 05-19 20:36:58.943: W/System.err(5175):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
  05-19 20:36:58.943: W/System.err(5175):   at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
  05-19 20:36:58.953: W/System.err(5175):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  05-19 20:36:58.953: W/System.err(5175): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
   05-19 20:36:58.963: W/System.err(5175):  at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
  05-19 20:36:58.963: W/System.err(5175):   at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
 05-19 20:36:58.963: W/System.err(5175):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
 05-19 20:36:58.963: W/System.err(5175):    ... 19 more
 05-19 20:36:59.413: D/gralloc_goldfish(5175): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

Comment: I think your file is just absent

Comment: i have tried by adding that private key file into asset folder and raw folder also but still am getting the same error